# How to get Keyboard Light keys working on Macbook?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, macbook

I've got a Macbook Pro with Keyboard Light brightness keys.  How to I make them work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `mactel` PPA by [following these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/PPA).

Install packages `applesmc-dkms` and `hid-dkms`.

Reboot.

`sudo vi /usr/local/bin/keyboard-backlight` and add:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALUE=$(cat /sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness)
INCREMENT=32
TOTAL=unset

case $1 in
up)
    TOTAL=`expr $VALUE + $INCREMENT`
    ;;
down)
    TOTAL=`expr $VALUE - $INCREMENT`
    ;;
full)
    TOTAL=255
    ;;
off)
    TOTAL=0
    ;;
esac

if [ $TOTAL == unset ]; then
    echo "Please specify up, down, full, or off"
    exit 1
fi

if [ $TOTAL -gt 255 ]; then TOTAL=255; fi
if [ $TOTAL -lt 0 ]; then TOTAL=0; fi 
echo $TOTAL > /sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

Followed by `sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/keyboard-backlight`.

`sudo visudo` and add the line:

```
your_username_goes_here ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/keyboard-backlight up, /usr/local/bin/keyboard-backlight down
```

Go to `System` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Add new shortcuts:

`Increase Keyboard Backlight Brightness`/`sudo keyboard-backlight up` and

`Decrease Keyboard Backlight Brightness`/`sudo keyboard-backlight down`.

Set each to the correct key by clicking the key mapping box and pressing the key.

Comment: Thanks, Jorge! It works with my Macbook Air (Early 2014) in Xubuntu 14.04 LTS. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Actually, I wrote this.  It is out of date, though.

Comment: Thanks, I can also confirm that this is working on Xubuntu 14.04-1 on a MacBookPro 11,2. Note that I had to install [`applesmc-dkms` from the quantal version](https://launchpad.net/~mactel-support/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=quantal), and failed to build/install `hid-dkms` but it didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest Ubuntu release - 11.04 - Natty Narwhal - and keyboard backlight should work out of the box - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/724324

Answer (score 0):

Use "pomme".
It is redundant (three programs all pop up to tell you that you increased your volume!), annoying, and doesn't work for me for this anyway (no effect).  However, others swear by it.  (Please edit this for how to make it work if you know.  Bonus for turning off the redundant parts.)