# Keyboard backlight: how to have it turn off automatically after x minutes of inactivity on Macbook Air

Tags: keyboard, brightness, macbook, backlight

Ik recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my Macbook Air (i5-4250U, 4Gb, 121 Gb). System works like a charm, except for one thing. I want the keyboard backlight to automatically dim / turn off after a  inactivity, this is important for my specific use of the laptop. It can be adjusted with F1/F2, but does not turn off after inactivity.

Anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Koen

EDIT: Before posting, I researched and found several topics on AskUbuntu on getting the keyboard backlight to work, but none of them addressing the issue I have. Hope this helps and prevents any further downvoting :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Keyboard Light keys working on Macbook?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26248/how-to-get-keyboard-light-keys-working-on-macbook)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @moo, but unfortunately it does not answer my question. In my case the backlight does work, but it does not turn off after inactivity.